# PHP: parse_ini_file works locally, but not on server

Tags: php

Good Day fellow Humans,
Working on a web application, and it is working as expected locally(PHP 7.3.5) However this is not working on our webserver which is running PHP7.2.20. (It might not be a version issue)
Here is a shorted version of the syntax i am executing.

```
$test =parse_ini_file("monitor_items\Citizens.properties");
var_dump($test);
```

The above works locally and outputs the expected properties, however when running the same file on our web server the out put is "bool(false)"

I've confirmed that the file is in the correct location, if i try to parse a file that doesn't exist, php will output that.

What else have I possibly overlooked? Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you all

Comment: Is your server running Windows? Because if not, then you want a forward slash, not a backslash, in your path.

Comment: Probably want a `/` anyways.

Comment: The content of the ini file might be invalid and/or access to the file is not possible. Please [edit] your question to include the content of the ini file and include the output of `var_dump($file="monitor_items\Citizens.properties", file_exists($file), is_readable($file), is_file($file));` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Niet and Abra!! That was exactly it, i switched it to a forward slash and it works on both windows(locally) and unix(server)